# Is string.hashCode stable over dart versions?

Tags: dart

Asking this because I notice when doing `print('${"abc".hashCode}');` on dartpad it gives `102006619`, whereas running it locally yields `756227931`.

my dart version:

```
$ dart --version
Dart SDK version: 2.9.0-21.10.beta (beta) (Tue Jul 21 10:46:30 2020 +0200) on "linux_x64"
```

Answer (score 2):

Then I guess the answer is "no".
Or maybe "it depends", or "it's complicated".

I don't believe Dart has changed the hash code algorithm for strings any time recently, but there is no promise that it won't happen. As such, it is probably stable between *versions*, but it's not a promise that it stays that way.

However, the algorithm may differ between *platforms*. Dart2js generated JavaScript, like the one running in DartPad, and native code run no the VM do differ in how they calculate the hash of a string. I don't know if the dev-compiler has a third version, but I'd guess that it's likely to follow dart2js.